# Select with Max() column does not return if colum is null

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have query like this

```
SELECT cus.id, cus.crawler_url_id, cus.created_at, cus.status
FROM crawler_url_stats cus
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, crawler_url_id, max( created_at ) latest
    FROM crawler_url_stats
    GROUP BY crawler_url_id
) cus2 ON ( cus.crawler_url_id = cus2.crawler_url_id
AND cus.created_at = cus2.latest )
ORDER BY `cus`.`crawler_url_id` ASC
```

It is a little modified version of query proposed in one of other topics, I just changed the `GROUP BY` in inner query to `crawler_url_id`(it is not `id`) and changed matching of join to `crawler_url_id` too.

Everything seems to work good, but there is a problem when the row `created_at` is empty for one of the `crawler_url_id`, for example I have 4 rows with `crawler_url_id` equal to `5` and if just one of them has `created_at` equal to `null` then the results won't contain the one with this `5` `crawler_url_id`.

Seems like strange bahaviour for me, first I tried the code from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/1951693, but it returned wrong results(multiple results per `crawler_url_id`) so I modified it and now it just struggles when there is null there.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between an INNER JOIN and an outer join?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and your desired results?

Comment: max(ifnull(field,0)) will set the null to 0 before the max is performed...is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Try to exclude rows with `NULL` from the subquery:

```
SELECT cus.id, cus.crawler_url_id, cus.created_at, cus.status
FROM crawler_url_stats cus
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, crawler_url_id, max( created_at ) latest
    FROM crawler_url_stats
    WHERE created_at IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY crawler_url_id
) cus2 ON ( cus.crawler_url_id = cus2.crawler_url_id
AND cus.created_at = cus2.latest )
ORDER BY `cus`.`crawler_url_id` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `max(ifnull(created_at, 0))` in both subquery and instead of `cus.created_at` works great. Solved.